# Moving data up a hierarchy of objects in Python

Tags: python, oop

I have a hierarchy of objects nested inside each other representing visual elements.
For example:

```
Window/
├─ Seperator/
│  ├─ Button
│  ├─ Scrollable/
│  │  ├─ TextView
```

If an error occurs in a lower object I can easily catch it higher up. For example, if the TextView is asked to scale lower than is possible it can throw an error which is then caught and handled by the Scrollable element.

My question is how can I achieve similar functionality for non-erroneous events.

My current possible solutions:

- A dictionary representing the event is passed up the tree until it reaches an object that can handle it
- Callback functions are passed down to every object.
- Raise errors for these events as well as actual errors.

However all of those solutions feel wrong.

Comment: What "feels wrong" about "both" of these 3 approaches?

Comment: Callback functions because you would have to manually pass them through every layer in the tree. Raising errors because the events are not errors. The dictionary because there are no restrictions on what it could contain and you'd also have to pass it through every layer. Though that may be my statically typed brain talking.

Comment: Your first two solutions don't seem mutually exclusive - to pass a dictionary 'up the tree' you would either need to do something like `self.parent.handle(event_dict)` or `self.parent_handle(event_dict)` where `parent_handle` is the callback function that has been passed down. Either of these seem okay but I would probably prefer the 2nd because it means the child object only has access to methods of the parent which have been deliberately passed down to it.